# When is a quotient $\mathbb Z$-algebra a ring quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, morphism

Suppose that I have two rings with identity, $S,R \in $ Ring, and a surjective $\mathbb Z$-algebra homomorphism $f: S \to R$ (hence $R$ is a quotient $\mathbb Z$-algebra of $S$).

Is it true that $R$ is also a quotient ring of $S$? I.e. can I choose a surjective $g: S \to R$ that is a ring homomorphism (hence it keeps the identity element)?

Comment: For me, the category of rings is equivalent to the category $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras. What are your definitions? Do I understand it correctly that for you a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra homomorphism doesn't have to send $1_S$ to $1_R$? Note that if $f:S\to R$ is a multiplicative and surjective map between two rings with identity, we must have $f(1)=1$. Indeed, if $s$ is a preimage of $1$, then $1=f(s)=f(s\cdot 1)=f(s)f(1)=f(1)$.

Comment: Yes, I meant that ring homomorphisms send 1 to 1. And indeed, you are perfectly right that multiplicative surjective maps send 1 to 1. 

If you post it as an answer, I will accept it immediately. If you don't, I will probably delete my original question, since the answer is quite trivial, and I shouldn't have posted it in the first place. It seems that I am a bit overzelous when it comes to posting to stackexchange.

Comment: I don't think you shouldn't have posted the question! I know the negative emotions that arise when realizing that a question one posted here has a trivial answer, and then it is on this forum for everyone to see. But I think one shouldn't feel bad about this (although I still do sometimes), because a question with a trivial answer is by no means a bad question. Its completely normal to sometimes miss a simple argument, and if you can resolve the situation by a quick forum post then everything about it should be something positive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $f:S\to R$ is a surjective and multiplicative map between two rings $S$ and $R$ with identity, then $f(1_S)=1_R$. Indeed, if $s$ is a preimage of $1$, then
$$
1=f(s)=f(s \cdot 1)=f(s)f(1)=f(1).
$$
In particular, a surjective, additive and multiplicative map between rings with identity is always a ring homomorphism.